# FusedLocationAPI returning null for the first time after adding permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-fusedlocation

I am implementing fusedLocationAPI in my app. For android phones with >= Marshmallow, I am adding up the permissions. The issue is for the first time after installation, the lat and long values are returned as null. But next time after starting the application, it is working fine. Below I am posting my code. Please have a look.

inside onCreate():

```
     manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        checkPermission();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        if (!statusOfGPS) {
            displayPromptForEnablingGPS(MainActivity.this);
        }
```

Other Methods:

```
      @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        checkPermission();
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        // Update location every second

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                lon = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                if (!String.valueOf(lat).equals("0.0")){
                    latitudeVal = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                    longitudeVal = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                    Log.e("Lat and Lng", String.valueOf(latitudeVal)+ longitudeVal);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }
        synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }
        public void displayPromptForEnablingGPS(final Activity activity) {
            final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            final String action = Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;
            final String message = "Do you want open GPS setting?";
            builder.setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                                    activity.startActivity(new Intent(action));
                                    d.dismiss();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                                    d.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            builder.create().show();
        }

    private void requestPermission() {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION };


    Activity activity =this;
    Context context = this;


    private  boolean checkPermission() {
        int result;
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String p:permissions) {
            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            }
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),10 );

            Log.d("permissionissue","no");
            return false;
        }
        Log.d("permissionissue","yes");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 101:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    checkPermission();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try {
                        Log.d("deniedOnes",permissions[0] + " Denied!!!");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code :

// Variable Declare

```
  final int MY_REQUEST_CODE=20;
```

// Method to ask permission

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AccountSettingActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AccountSettingActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AccountSettingActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AccountSettingActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AccountSettingActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           // do your Task here 
        }
    } else {
        // do your Task here

    }
```

Now  on `permissionResult` write this :

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            // do your Task here 
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelling, required permissions are not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to get location update if location from FusedLocationProviderClient is null. For Eg:

```
mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

            if (location == null) {
                startGPS();
            } else {
                startIntentService(location);
            }
        }
    });
```

public void startGPS() {

```
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)SmileMore.appContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
}
```

private void initLocationListener() {

```
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if(location == null){
                return;
            }
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this); // remove this listener as soon as you get first location update.
            startIntentService(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
}
```